# GZipStream does not call underlying streams *Async methods when destination of CopyToAsync

Tags: c#, async-await, gzipstream

Using the following construct for a GZipStream it never seems to call the *Async method of my custom stream when `GZipStream` is the destination of `CopyToAsync`.

```
using (var fs = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\BTR\Source\Assemblies\BTR.Rbl.Evolution.Documents.dll", 
        System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.None, 8192, true))
{
    using (var ss = new GZipStream(new MyCustomStream(), CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        await fs.CopyToAsync(ss);
    }
}
```

It seems to only call the `BeginWrite/EndWrite` mechanisms.  Is there a way to derive from `GZipStream` to make it call `WriteAsync` instead so that my custom stream doesn't have to implement both the `WriteAsync` method along with the `BeginWrite/EndWrite` methods?

You can find a working sample of this [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GEwe0w)

**Update: Callstack when initial `Write()` method called**

```
SampleStream.Write(buffer, offset, count)
System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.DoMaintenance(array, offset, count)
System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.InternalWrite(array, offset, count, isAsync)
System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(msg, replySink)
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.AgileAsyncWorkerItem.ThreadPoolCallBack(o)
System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(state)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(executionContext, callback, state, preserveSyncCtx)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(executionContext, callback, state, preserveSyncCtx)
System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
(Unmanaged code)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be more correct for your custom stream to implement `BeginWrite`/`EndWrite` (and `BeginRead`/`EndRead` as well). It's not hard if you use my [`AsyncEx.Tasks` library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/1.2.0-alpha-01):

```
public override IAsyncResult BeginWrite(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count,
    AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
  var task = WriteAsync(buffer, offset, count);
  return ApmAsyncFactory.ToBegin(task, callback, state);
}

public override void EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
  ApmAsyncFactory.ToEnd(asyncResult);
}
```

(`ApmAsyncFactory` has been added to the `1.2.0-alpha-01` version of `AsyncEx.Tasks`).

Comment: Where is ApmAsyncFactory at?  I can't find it in the library.

Comment: @Terry: You need to install the preview version for `ApmAsyncFactory`. I just haven't rolled out version `1.2.0` yet.

Comment: I haven't looked at your code, but before this question I tried to make `BeginWrite/EndWrite` leverage my `WriteAsync` by trying to follow https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178(v=vs.110).aspx.  I'm by **no means** a Tasks expert, but my attempt got the same strange result as your code is producing (maybe you are just wrapping their suggestions?).  When calling `CopyToAsync` with `Console.WriteLine` in `Write` and `WriteAsync` I get 1 `Write`, then tons of `WriteAsync` then end with 3 `Write`.  Any idea why I'm not getting **all** `WriteAsync` dumps?  Or is that expected?

Comment: @Terry: That's strange. I have no idea why `CopyToAsync` would call `Write`. I'd take a look at the stack when it calls your `Write`.

Comment: I updated the question to display the stack.  I tried digging into Reference Source, but admittedly, this is beyond my thread coding skills.  Do you see anything odd there, or just going with the assumption that all is OK?

Comment: @Terry: It's odd and inefficient, but it should *work* fine.